# Only display item hovered on react after map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am really surprised this isn't working as I anticipated.

I want to show a username when the the person visiting the site hovers over the users's message. Below is the code I have so far. The problem is that when I hover over the message every username in the array that I have mapped over appears. How can I change this so that it is only one username?

I guess I need to change the state to each user's message in a separate component, however, I wouldn't have thought this should be neccessary.

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        showUsername: false
    };

    showUsername = () => {

        this.setState({
            showUsername: true
        });

    }

    hideUsername = () => {

        this.setState({
            showUsername: false
        });

    }

    render() {

        let messageArr = this.props.messages.map(msg => {

            let name = `${msg.firstName} ${msg.lastName}`;

            return(
                <div key={msg.id}>

                    {this.state.showUsername && (
                        <span>{name}</span>
                    )}

                    <li><span onMouseEnter={this.showUsername} onMouseLeave{this.hideUsername}>{msg.message}</span></li>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul>
                {messageArr}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I need to change the state to each user's message in a separate component, however, I wouldn't have thought this should be necessary.

yes.Its necessary.

As of now,there is one common state `showUsername` is used to show user's name   which is why you getting  this effect.

```
showUsername = (oneUserMessage) => {

    oneUserMessage.showUsername = true; // updating via reference
}

hideUsername = (oneUserMessage) => {

    oneUserMessage.showUsername = false;// updating via reference

}
```

//return in render

```
return (
            <div key={msg.id}>

                {msg.showUsername && (
                    <span>{name}</span>
                )}
                <li><span 
                  onMouseEnter={()=>{this.showUsername(msg)}} 
                  onMouseLeave={()=>{this.hideUsername(msg)}}>       
                  {msg.message}</span></li>


            </div>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your components are behaving like this, because `this.state.showUsername` is a state inside your component. 
So, whichever div is hovered, it will set the `state` to `true`, and all of your others will receive `this.state.showUsername` as `true` either.

This makes all of them visible.

What you should do is, write a new component having the `div` and the logic inside of it. So when you map it down, you each of these `divs` will have its own states.

Another thing, you can do the map like this:

```
        const messageArr = this.props.messages.map((msg) => <div key={msg.id}>
            <li>
               <span onMouseEnter={this.showUsername} onMouseLeave{this.hideUsername}>{msg.message}</span>
            </li>

        </div>);
```

So no need for the return statement :)